# Solution techniques for f'(x)=f(g(x))

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

I stumbled over this seemingly natural question and was surprised, that I couldn't find a satisfying answer. 
Differential equations of the type $f'(x)=g(f(x))$ are studied for all kind of classes of g, but what is there to say about solutions to the opposite case where $f'(x)=f(g(x))$? I even failed to find solutions for the very simple case $f'(x)=f(1-x)$, say on domain $[0,1]$. 
Ultimately I am looking for solutions to 
$ f'(x)=\frac{1-f(x)}{f(1-x)-1+x} $.
Thank you for any helpful comments.

Comment: The equation $f'(x) = f(1-x)$ and your more general ODE on the interval $[1/2,1]$ are types of *delay differential equations*. You might start looking there for ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Regarding what I found on wikipedia concerning DDE I am not very optimistic to find analytical solutions to my problem :-(